# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

```
$getCart=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT ID, productTitle, manufacturer, cost FROM Products LEFT JOIN shopCart
  ON 'Products.ID'='ShopCart.productID'");

$getCart->execute();
```

Am gettting error at `$getCart->execute();` line:

**'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'ID' in field list is ambiguous**

I've read related questions, but i haven't found solution yet.

Here is my simple Db picture:
[image]

Comment: You need to tell MySQL if you mean `Products.ID` or `ShopCart.id`. `SELECT ID, productTitle, manufacturer` <-- here

Comment: Always use qualified column names (with the table alias).  Then you won't ever have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use 2 tables with JOIN, you have to precise your table :

```
$getCart=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT Products.ID, productTitle, manufacturer, cost FROM Products LEFT JOIN shopCart
  ON 'Products.ID'='ShopCart.productID'");
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect in multiple ways.  You probably intend something like this:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.productTitle, p.manufacturer, sc.cost
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     shopCart sc
     ON p.ID = sc.productID;
```

Notes:

- The tables are given aliases which are abbreviations of the table names.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.
- All column references are qualified, so it is clear (both to people and to SQL engines) where the column is coming from.  I am just guessing on the source of the columns.
- The `on` clause has no single quotes, because comparing two string constants is generally not useful.